# How to download and print in web using js

Tags: javascript, web, printing, download

How can we take a print or download of a document or a form uploaded by us.
Is it free or paid??
Thanks in advance
Happy Coding!!
[Check this link also](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/2447891/print-and-download-in-html-using-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print the page, use `window.print()` in JavaScript.
You can then also print to PDF file.

If you want to do it yourself, manually, just press Ctrl + P.